# Make a VStack inside a ScrollView take up all remaining space

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Given a `ScrollView`, how do I make a `VStack` inside it, occupy all the remaining space?

In the code below, I want the bottom VStack to take up all the remaining space in the screen. I've tried setting `maxHeight` to `infinity` but nothing has worked so far. The intended outcome is for the yellow VStack to take the entire screen.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Title")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding(.leading)

                    Spacer()
                }

                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: 60)

                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Text("Header Text")
                }
                .frame(height: 60)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(6.5)
                .padding(.horizontal)

                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: 60)

                // I want this to occupy all the remaining space
                VStack {
                    Text("ABC")

                    Text("DEF")
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.yellow)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.green.ignoresSafeArea())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue lies within combination of `ScrollView` and `VStack`. By default, `ScrollView` only takes up the place required by its child view, which stopped `VStack` from expanding. One solution is use `GeomtryReader` as you can see in following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { gm in  //----> add it here
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Title")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .padding(.leading)

                        Spacer()
                    }

                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 60)

                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text("Header Text")
                    }
                    .frame(height: 60)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(6.5)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 60)

                    // I want this to occupy all the remaining space
                    VStack {
                        Text("ABC")

                        Text("DEF")
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: gm.size.height) // ----> use it here
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color.green.ignoresSafeArea())
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(edges: [.bottom])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! We're almost there but the bottom of the VStack does not cover the entire ScrollView's background. Even adding a constant to `gm.size.height` or applying `ignoresSafeArea` to `Color.yellow` did not work

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand your point what you want to achieve but as per your question i added code for what you want